# Css simple modal rules

Tags: javascript, html, css, modal-dialog

i have a simple modal divs:

```
<div class="modal"></div>
<div class="modal-content"></div>
```

then theyr related Css rules:

```
.modal{position:fixed;background:#444;opacity:0.5;width:100%;height:100%;left:0;right:0;bottom:0;top:0;}
.modal-content{position:fixed;background:#fff;width:auto;height:auto;top:25%;left:25%;right:25%;}
```

what i would like is that .modal-content remains always centered on page with a max-width of 500px; while width:auto;

is it possible to do without using js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about adding

```
max-width:500px;
margin:0 auto 0 auto;
```

to .modal-content

Hope that's what you were looking for, cheers.

Comment: i added but it results not centered on page :P

Comment: Hi, also try adding margin:0 auto 0 auto 0; to that. Works fine on my side now.

Comment: nope ... i'm on FF6 .. 
.modal-content{position:fixed;background:#fff;margin:0 auto  0 auto 0;width:900px;right:0;left:0;height:auto;top:25%;} it doesn't works (is not centered)

Comment: Hi, this is working here on FF6, please try:

.modal-content{position:fixed;background:#fff;height:auto;top:25%;left:25%;right:25%;min-width:10px; max-width:500px; margin:0 auto 0 auto;}

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit tricky, but can be achieved. Have a look here for some examples:
http://www.jakpsatweb.cz/css/css-vertical-center-solution.html

A lot easier to do with Javascript and jQuery though, especially if your container can have a fixed position. What browsers do you need to support?

Comment: Hehe, ok. Anyway, I'd really recommend you to do it with Javascript as it will save you quite a lot of headache and time. If you're worried about the few users not able/wanting to run Javascript, you could always create a simple fallback with pure CSS where it doesn't center the same way.

Comment: ok .. :)   and what about js (i use jQuery) if i want to add to .modal-content centered on page with position:fixed; and max-width:500px; ? :P